# WPF Button's Command-Binding not working when launched from WinForms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have a UserControl with two buttons in my Window. The UserControl has it's own DataContext with two corresponding Commands.

Naturally, the binding on the buttons was written like this

```
Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
```

**However**, we have two launch mechanisms for our modules: one is via a WPF launcher and the other is via our old WinForms menu. If we use the **WinForms** menu, the binding does not work anymore. Instead the following Binding was the only way to make it work.

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.SaveCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
```

Is this due to WinForms in combination with the way commands bubble up or something along those lines?

**Note 1:** Other modules seem not to be afflicted somehow. It might really be this exact structure / the double DataContext (window/control)

**Note 2:** It might be worth noting that we use Telerik's RadButton instead of regular buttons.

Comment: The problem is that the UserControl has its own "private" view model. Why does it have that instead of exposing bindable properties like any other control? If the sole purpose of the private view model is to implement those two commands, you could as well drop it and implement two Button Click handlers in the control's code behind.

Comment: The datacontext / viewmodel is working just fine, apart from the commands that stop working only in combination with the WinForms launcher. I generally disagree that controls should never have their own view model. There are reasons for that. Either way, and since we've already found a solution. I'm much more interested in the underlying problem why the commands stop working with WinForms.